# Admob banner won't show up

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

So I am learning Java and testing out what I have learned so far.
I have a random number generator and got it to work :)

Now I wanted to try adding Google Admob but whatever I do, it just wont show up on my app! No error messages during the build.

When I tried to use sample ids with blank activity (so just one banner ad showing on blank activity) it worked fine but as soon as I do the same on my project with my own ad +banner id, it won't show up..

First my Manifest,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.todayluckynumber">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Lucky Lotto Max Number"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-5591413578175283~3345461526"/>

    <activity android:name=".lotto649" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Now my module gradle, (project gradle is set up well with google)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.todayluckynumber"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'}
```

Now I have two activity running with intent but I will just put my main page as both of them don't work

My Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LinearLayout ll;
ArrayList<Bitmap> lottoBalls;
Button bt;
AdView mAdView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5591413578175283/1605004449");

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.admon);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

  
    lottoBalls = new ArrayList<>();

    
    Resources res = getResources();

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

        
        int tmpId = getResources().getIdentifier( "lottoball" + (i+1) , "drawable", 
  getPackageName());

        
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, tmpId)
                ,150,300, true);

      
        lottoBalls.add(bitmap);
    }

        ll = findViewById(R.id.ll);
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout
                .LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ll.setLayoutParams(param);

        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        bt = findViewById(R.id.bt);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                
                if(ll.getChildCount() > 0) ll.removeAllViews();

                
                TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet();

               
                while(set.size() < 7){

                   
                    int random = new Random().nextInt(49);

                 
                    set.add(random);
                }

                    
                    for(Integer i:set){

                        
                        ImageView lottoBallView = new ImageView(ll.getContext());

                     
                        lottoBallView.setImageBitmap(lottoBalls.get(i));

                       
                        ll.addView(lottoBallView);

                        }
                    }
        });
}
public void maxi (View c) {
    Intent k = new Intent(this,lotto649.class);
    startActivity(k);

}}
```

Now my HTML

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="MY Lucky Number"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/admon"
    android:layout_width="392dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5591413578175283/1605004449">
    
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text='Ball Image from https://www.vecteezy.com/free-vector/balls">Balls Vectors by 
     Vecteezy'
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text='Ball Image from https://www.vecteezy.com/free-vector/balls">Balls Vectors by 
     Vecteezy' />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/maxi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:onClick="maxi"
        android:text="what is my Lucky Lotto 649 Number?"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-admob-banner-ads-android-studio/#:~:text=Add%20the%20following%20code%20to,App%20ID%20in%20AdMob%20console.&text=filter_none-,Add%20the%20highlighted%20code%20to,xml%20to%20show%20banner%20ad.
```

This link will help you to get some idea about addMob banners. Refer this link and solve your problem.